# can't install dependency during python heroku deployment

Tags: python, web, heroku, pytorch, cloud

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
future==0.18.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1,
numpy==1.19.2,
Pillow==7.2.0,
torch==1.5.0+cpu,
torchvision==0.6.0+cpu,
Werkzeug==1.0.1,
```

these are the required dependency for my web app although there ar two dependency which does not install directly via pip install torch and torchvision package but rather via
pip install torch==1.5.0+cpu torchvision==0.6.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

but while deploying to heroku we have to create a requirements.txt file so is there a way to explicitly mention the source in the requirements.txt file.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just add the link on the very top and pip installer will automatically look into it when installing packages.

```
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
future==0.18.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1,
numpy==1.19.2,
Pillow==7.2.0,
torch==1.5.0+cpu,
torchvision==0.6.0+cpu,
Werkzeug==1.0.1,
```